# How to get substring in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract special word from a sentence in SQL Server.

For example I want to extract `No-13` from `'Street3 NO-13 Floor 4th'`

Following code is my primary code, but I can't find the last index to get special word:

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%Y[^][0-9]%', 'Street3 NO-13 Floor 4th')
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex natively. You'll need to either create CLR functions, or use a different language.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I found a solution, I use following code:

```
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(255)
SET @txt = 'Street3 NO- 13 Floor 4th'
DECLARE @startIndex INT
SELECT @startIndex = PATINDEX('% No%[0-9]%',@txt) 
Declare @FirstLetters AS NVARCHAR(50)   
DECLARE @remainingString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @remainingString = SUBSTRING(@txt, @startIndex, LEN(@txt) - @startIndex)
SELECT @FirstLetters=SUBSTRING(@remainingString, 0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@remainingString))

SELECT @remainingString=REPLACE(@remainingString,@FirstLetters,'')  

SELECT @FirstLetters +LEFT(
             SubString(@remainingString, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @remainingString), 8000), 
                 PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(@remainingString, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', 
@remainingString), 8000) + 'X')-1) AS BuildingNo
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of the pattern is fixed, so you always know where the pattern ends. However, it seems that what you really want is to find the end of a word that *starts* with a given pattern. If you only care about spaces as word separators, this is quite simple - `charindex` takes an optional starting location index, so you can just find the first space *after* the `patindex` result. Then you can use `substring` to get the string between the two indices.

Comment: No, I don't know the length of my special word, it is just example.